# How do I turn the following data into a Python dict

Tags: python, json

I'm very new to programming and picking Python as my first language. I am able to do a "POST" via an API but how do I convert the response I get below to a Python dictionary?

If were to print the response directly I only get:

```
Response [201]
```

But if I were to do:

```
for i in response:
    print i
```

I get:

```
{"id":"9e1ebc5d","side":"buy","item":"dinosaur","type":"limit","amount":"1.0000","displayAmount":"1.0000","price":"100","createdTime":"2014-12-24T16:01:15.3404000Z","status":"submitted","metadata":{}}
```

However this is still pretty much useless to me unless I can figure out how convert this into a Python dict.

Comment: What type is `response`? It appears to be an iterable of some type whose `__str__` method prints a simple response code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `loads` function from the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module:

```
import json

# let x be a string contain the JSON encoded data
x = '{"id":"9e1ebc5d", ...}'

# convert to Python dictionary
p = json.loads(x)

# p is now a Python dictionary
print type(p) # prints   <type 'dict'>
print p['id'] # prints   9e1ebc5d
```